# rewriting an Url

Tags: url-rewriting

I have an url like: http://domain.com/event/?filter_location=77&location=name_of_location

I want a clean url like http://domain.com/event/name_of_location/77

How do I accomplish this in wordpress?

Comment: What is "event" here? What are the arguments in the query?

Comment: event is a page listing custom post type `events`

Comment: @waterschaats So then use my method below... it will work if event is a category like I stated.

Comment: Event is a custom-post-type not a category and filter_location is the ID of another custom-post-type. It can't be done the way you explained

Answer (score -1):

You can customise the way your links are generated by going to the admin menu of WordPress then settings -> permalinks.

There will be multiple options to choose from or you may construct a 'custom' permalink structure to fit your needs.

So in your case, you may want to use the custom structure option and put something like `%category%/%postname%` if the `event` in your URL is a category.

Comment: Why is my answer downvoted? This **is** how you alter your urls in wordpess...

Comment: (not the downvoter) What you explained is how to set permalinks. What OP needs is redirects. `filter_location` and `location` are not part of permalink structure

Comment: @kero Not by default no, but I'm sure they can be set up to use for that purpose.